# Managing 2008 R2 from outside domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to use Windows Remote Server Management from a client not joined to domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, so long as you can supply some valid domain credentials, with the correct rights.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the runas feature on a non-domain computer with domain credentials.